# Return unique report/list/table based on user entered criteria pushed through series of decision trees

Tags: web-apps, data-analysis, survey

I am looking for an application that will allow me to have a user answer a series of dynamic questions.  At the end of the process, a table or report will be generated with information unique to each location or other criteria.

For example, a client has a widget that is going to the US, Spain, and Australia. The process would start with general characteristics and geographies. Then it would address the unique concerns for each geography - maybe Spain has particular product testing requirement that the others don't have.

Once all info is collected, that data would be run through a logic that could determine the needs for each country (think regulatory requirements - government registrations). A report and/or table would be the deliverable.

My requirements are,

- The software to either be Web based or integrated into Office 365 (including SharePoint Online, Access, Project) - I'm looking for an easy to use interface which would not include for instance a command line application

If possible, I would like the application to be,

- Either form or table based, use deliverable in other applications (export), modular (able to make additions without reworking entire setup), email deliverable to designated recipient
- Gratis

Comment: I edited the question to remove the request for "do it myself" options even though both answers that were provided prior to the hold were fantastic and very helpful. I will create a separate post in a more appropriate forum to address that question - hopefully I don't get flagged as cross posting.. Thank you.

Comment: Is this still on hold?

Comment: As you can see. It required 5 votes to be closed, now it requires 5 votes to be re-opened. Btw: What is "Frosting free"? Did you rather mean "free of cost"?

Comment: As in "the frosting on the cake."  It is a turn of phrase common in the US. I'll edit again. So, do i have to lobby to get my question reopened? Sorry, I am new and am not used to the level of moderation i am seeing.

Comment: Thanks, Jamison; not all of us here are English native speakers (I'm not, for example). And no, lobbying doesn't work much here. I nominated your question for reopening; now either 4 more users or 1 mod must throw in their weight. Might take a little, depending on how many users with the necessary rep are online and watching the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms?

**Pros:**

```
No programming to learn
simple web based interface
Can distribute via email
Automatically collects the results for you in a spreadsheet
Free
```

**Cons**

```
It is a bit awkward.  For example:
You have to create new pages for each condition.
```

What country do you live in?
Page 1
English goto page 2
Spanish goto page 3
Australian goto page 4

Page 2
Language?
English Page 5
Spanish page 6
Vulcan  page 7

Page 3
Language?
Spanish page 8
Klingon page 9
Romulan page 10

Page 4
Language?
Australian  pg 11
english     pg 12
Scooby      pg 13

Unfortunately, after selecting US and English you would need to start at page 14 for those questions.  You could easily have 100 pages after you branch each one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reasonable chance that your main differences between pages will be:

- Language
- Possibly the names of Regulatory Authorities

I would suggest looking at the GNU [GetText](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) internationalization, ([i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)), pages on how to make international code.  Several programming languages support i18n - personally I would opt for [python](http://python.org) which has lots of reporting tools and good [i18n support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/i18n.html) and one of the many python web frameworks such [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) with the pages generated programmatically and any country specific pages inserted into the decision tree at need.

One of the lovely things about this approach is that you don't have to rewrite your software when a new language is added, just add to the catalog of translations.